# shortcut like in windows

Tags: bash, shell, files

Can I make shortcut like in Win, which will be visible in folder from (almost) every program (cli like mc and gui - any open file dialog) that will "move" me to specific directory, not related to location of shortcut?
SO when I will go up (after using this) I don't want to get back, but go up.

Example:

```
/home/jarek/some_link -> /srv/httpd/htdocs/projekt
```

I'm using link, and I want check some other files in htdocs, click up (or cd ..) and ordinary soft link take my back to ~ and I want to htdocs.

ps. I saw posts about differences in `pwd` and `/bin/pwd` and nice to know that I can check where I really am, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Tigger, read the question more closely (especially the line I quoted in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

> ...ordinary soft link take my back to ~ and I want to htdocs.

What you want is the `-P` option to `cd`.

To read up on how the current working directory is kept track of, both for the shell and for *any* process, see:

- [What does it mean each process has a current directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74249/135943)

However, for purposes of traversing symlinks, the important thing to understand is that the actual named path that you pass to `cd` *becomes* your "current working directory."  In your example, `pwd` would show `/home/jarek/some_link`, and as you correctly note, `cd ..` would take you to `/home/jarek`, not to `/srv/httpd/htdocs`.

If instead you run `pwd -P`, you will see `/srv/httpd/htdocs/projekt`.  And if you run `cd -P .` and then `cd ..`, you will be in `/srv/httpd/htdocs` as you want.  Running `cd -P ..` will also work fine; I've just checked.

Run `help cd` and `help pwd` for full information.

Comment: Thanks, it should help witch console, and what about GUI open dialog?
btw, it still isn't modification of link. Does it mean that you can't do that type of link in Linux?